# ssh does not find /usr/local/bin path

Tags: bash, ssh, profile

If I log in to my remote Mac via `ssh -p22 jenkins@192.168.2.220` and type `docker`, it finds the executable because it also finds the path `/usr/local/bin` if I check with `echo $PATH`. But if I do the same in a heredoc inside a file `setup-mac.sh` like

```
#!/bin/bash
ssh jenkins@192.168.2.220 '/bin/bash -s' << 'EOF'
"echo $PATH" 
"bash run-docker.sh"
EOF
```

which I execute via shell and `bash setup-mac.sh` it does not find `/usr/local/bin` in `PATH` and consequently does not run docker, because the command is unknown.

On the remote Mac, there is a file `run-docker.sh` which is a bash file that calls docker commands, and it works if called locally.

To solve this issue, I've enabled `PermitUserEnvironment` on the mac in `sshd_config`, but this did not work. Though I only restarted ssh service and not the whole machine. Meanwhile I've changed all docker commands on the remote `run-docker.sh` script to an alias `${DOCKER}` and I initialize it at the beginning of the script to `DOCKER=/usr/local/bin/docker`, but this is only a workaround.

Comment: What’s the full path for the run-docker.sh file?

Comment: the `docker-run.sh` file is in `/Users/jenkins/Desktop/winlin/ubuntu`.

Comment: Please include complete error messages. See  [Why should I post complete errors? Why isn't the message itself enough?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359146/why-should-i-post-complete-errors-why-isnt-the-message-itself-enough)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess that the problem is occurring because `/usr/local/bin` is being added to the `PATH` by the 'jenkins' user's personal initialization file (`~/.bashrc`).  That is run only by interactive shells, and the shell run by `ssh ... '/bin/bash -s' ...` is not interactive.

You could try forcing the shell to be interactive by invoking it with `/bin/bash -i -s`, but that is likely to cause other problems.  (The shell may try and fail to set up job control.  The value of `PS1` may appear in outputs. ...)

In general, you can't rely on the `PATH` being set correctly for programs.  See [Setting the PATH in Scripts - Scripting OS X](https://scriptingosx.com/2018/02/setting-the-path-in-scripts/) for a thorough analysis of the problem.  [Correct way to use Linux commands in bash script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53196702/4154375) is also relevant, but doesn't have much information.

A simple and reliable way to fix the problem permanently is to set the required PATH explicitly at the start of `run-docker.sh`.  For example:

```
export PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin
```

You may need to add other directories to the path if `run-docker.sh` runs programs that are in other locations.

Another solution to the problem is to use full paths to commands in code.  However, that makes the code more difficult to read, more difficult to maintain, and more difficult to test.  Setting a safe `PATH` is usually a better option.